# Data roaming indicator AVP in the diameter request

Tags: telecommunication, diameter-protocol

Please any one tell me how we will identify the roaming/non-roaming subscribers from the diameter CCR initial request.

Answer (score 3):

For Gx reference point, you have two ways:

1. using MCC MNC

> AVP name: <3GPP-SGSN-MCC-MNC>
>
> AVP code: <18>

Anything is not your home (or national roaming MNC), is international roaming

2. Using SGSN IP adress

> AVP name <3GPP-SGSN-Address>
>
> AVP code: <6>

If you don't recognize IP adress of home SGSN it is roaming.

I have tested both on E/// equipment.

Comment: I think this question would be better adressed in the more specific QA site Telecommunications proposed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/104688/telecommunications
If you like the proposal, ask your question there and follow the proposal as well

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention which Diameter protocol you are using.
But anyway I dont think there is such an AVP.

In different protocols you have different AVPs that can give you hints about the user HPLMN and than you can compare them to whatever you have and understand if the user is from your PLMN.

Answer (score 0):

Too new here to vote for the answer above, but MCC MNC is what we use.  If they don't match your home networks' MCC's and MNC's, then assume roaming.